# Rescaling a function.

Tags: probability-theory

I have two probability density functions
$$f(x) =  \frac{\alpha}{((x+1)^{\alpha+1})}$$ 
and
$$g(x) =  \frac{\lambda}{(\lambda x+1)^2}$$
Now it seems that you can obtain the function $f(x)$ by rescaling $g(x)$. How should that be done exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You may get $f$ from $g$.
$$
f_\alpha(x) = \frac{\alpha}{(x+1)^{\alpha+1}}
$$
so 
$$
f_1(x)dx = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx =  \frac{\lambda d\tilde{x}}{(\lambda \tilde{x}+1)^2} = g(\tilde{x})d\tilde{x}
$$
where we used the substitution $x = \lambda\tilde{x}$.